# In FreePlane (mind mapper), how can I expand or enlarge a node?

Tags: mind-mapping, freemind

I have a node in my Freeplane mind map where the text doesn't all fit in the standard node size. Is there any way to resize a node larger?
I'm using Freeplane 1.5.7beta.

Answer (score 2):

The [only way I've found](https://sourceforge.net/p/freemind/discussion/22102/thread/23dca310/?SetFreedomCookie) is by Alt+Enter on the node (or right-click and "Edit node core in dialog"), switch to "HTML Code view", and modify the `<body>` to contain the desired `width`, e.g., `<body width="500">`.

Answer (score 1):

Holding Alt on your keyboard while the pointer is over the desired node or you have already selected multiple nodes, just scroll to change the size